# React.js component run error. Uncaught TypeError: this.state.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a `Fetch` component, which should send a `POST` request return a response content. My problem is how to get the result data in `App`component. I got a error in chrome like this: [image]

Here is my js code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Request from 'react-http-request';


class Fetch extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {postResult: ''};

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Request
                url='http://localhost:8080/path'
                method='post'
                accept='application/json'
                type="application/json"
                send='{"law":"The First Law", "character":"No.1 Character"}'
               verbose={true}
            >
                {
                    ({error, result, loading}) => {
                        if (loading) {
                            return <div>loading...</div>;
                        } else {
                            this.state.setState({postResult: postResult});
                            return <div>{JSON.stringify(result)}</div>;
                           }
                        }
                }
            </Request>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {test: ''};
    }

    render() {

        this.state.setState({test: (<Fetch  />)});


        return (

            <table>
                <thead>

                <tr>

                    {this.state.test}


                </tr>

                </thead>


            </table>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('react'))
```

I don't know how to get result data from `Fetch` component, It troubled me.

Comment: Try this.setState(...) as opposed.

Comment: There is no function as this.state.setState and the error clearly specifies it. Read the docs in such cases

Comment: There is nothing like this.state.setState. For initializing state in the constructor use this.state ={ }. For modifying / updating the state frmo any another part use this.setState({object})

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using

```
this.state.setState({postResult: postResult});
```

You should use

```
this.setState({postResult: postResult});
```

The error is in this fragment of your code

```
                    if (loading) {
                        return <div>loading...</div>;
                    } else {
                        this.state.setState({postResult: postResult});
                        return <div>{JSON.stringify(result)}</div>;
                       }
                    }
            }
        </Request>
```

**Explanation:**

`this` references to an object of the `Fetch` class, that inherits the `setState()` method from `React.Component` class.

`this.state` is a plain object that holds data only, and has no functions to be executed. (it has no `setState()`)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this.state.setState({postResult: postResult});

this.setState means that you are modifying your current state to new values that you have updated in your this.setState function.

this.state.setState will never be called as state object does not provide us any such function
so change it to this.setState